# Socket.IO with single player game with smartphone as a controlling device

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to build a single player game (point and click), where you can use your cellphone as a controlling device. I've created login for a user where he/she can choose between keyboard and cell controlling.

After user clicks on "cell" he gets redirect to a game page. On a page he gets a randomly rendered URL to type into the cell URL, to connect two devices.

So I've ended up with 5 files:

1. game_mob.jade (Here is where user lands after login and this url is randered):

   ```
    h3#mobileUrlStart www.apopkalypse.com/mob/#{randomUrl}
   ```
2. game_mob_ctrl.jade (actual controls for the game, this is rendered for cell phone screen):

   ```
    .controls
      button#goUp Up
      button#goDown Down
      button#goLeft Left
      button#goRight Right
   ```
3. script_mobile.js (client side js for browser screens):

   ```
   var currentUrl = $('#mobileUrlStart').text();
   var roomName = currentUrl.substr(currentUrl.length - 5);
   var socket = io.connect('/game_play');

   if(roomName){
     socket.emit('join_room', roomName );
   }

   var move = false;

   socket.on('goUp', function() {
     move = setInterval(function() {
       $('.animate-box').animate({
         top: "-=30px"
       }, 'fast');
     }, 250);
   });
   ```
4. script_mob_ctrl.js (client side js for cell controls):

   ```
   // Get the room Name via URL
   var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
   var roomName = currentUrl.substr(currentUrl.length - 5);


   var socket = io.connect('/game_play');
   socket.on('established', function() {
     log('&#9733; Connection established.');
   });


   if(roomName){
     socket.emit('join_room', roomName );
   }

   $('#goUp').mousedown(function(e) {
     socket.emit('goUp', '');
   });
   ```
5. server side script in socket.js:

   ```
   var io = require('socket.io');
   exports.initialize = function(server){
     io = io.listen(server);
     var gamePlay = io.of("/game_play").on('connection', function(socket) {

     socket.on("join_room", function(room){
       socket.join(room);
     });

     io.socket.in(room).emit('goUp', function(data, ack) {
         io.sockets.emit('goUp');
       }); 
     });
   };
   ```

Everything was working until I started to play with "rooms". But I need a separate room for every player. Any ideas, how can I improve it? Or where are my mistakes?

Comment: socket IDs can be used for unique rooms for each user like socket.join(socket.id);

Comment: Thanx for answer! :) but can you write an example, I'm totally new to this. How can I listen on both devices for same Id?